# best way to link to a vignette from manual in an R package

Tags: r, devtools, vignette

I'm developing an R package, and I'm trying to make a link from the manual of the package to its vignette (a pdf). I've make this in the R function code, and it works:

```
\link[=../doc/package.pdf]{package's User Manual}
```

The problem is that the devtools::check() complains with a warning, which also causes a delay in the process of revision when uploading to CRAN...

```
* checking Rd cross-references ... WARNING   
Missing link or links in documentation object 'package.Rd':   
'../doc/package.pdf'
```

Is there a better way of linking from man to vignette? or it is not correct to do so? As the pdf can contain more graphical information, it seems desirable to be able to link to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pkgdown to make a website out of your package, then you can directly link to the url of the specific vignette.

Or you can just write

> Run \code{vignette("NAME_OF_YOUR_VIGNETTE", package = "NAME_OF_YOUR_PACKAGE")} to see the corresponding vignette.

Comment: Thanks F. Privé. But I'm trying to embed the link in the manual page that R itself shows.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case that code just show what is between braces, directly on the man page (as if it were typed code).